# Vim: restore cursor position after undo of imap

Tags: vim, undo, cursor-position

I have modified the `IMAP` function from `vim-latex`, so that an undo is possible, by changing the final return line of `LookupCharacter` to

```
return a:char . "^Gu\<bs>" . bs . IMAP_PutTextWithMovement(rhs, phs, phe)
```

Now to do the undo directly from insert mode, I have this mapping in my `.vimrc`:

```
imap <Undo> <Esc>ui
```

I use the [Neo2 keyboard layout](http://www.neo-layout.org), so there's an undo key on the 4th layer.

Now this works fairly well, but the problem is that when I use it at the end of a line, the cursor is placed *before* the last character. To test it without `vim-latex`, you could do

```
:imap a a^Gu\<bs>test
```

type 'b' in the middle and at the end of a line and then execute the undo, by shortcut or by manually pressing `<Esc>ui`.

So is there a way to make `vim` jump back to the correct cursor position?

I have seen [an entry in wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_the_cursor_position_after_undoing_text_change_made_by_a_script) which gives an idea, but I don't know how to achieve it with the `imap` mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor move is due to the indiscriminate use of `i` at the end of your mapping. Typically, one temporarily executes a normal mode command via

```
imap <Undo> <C-\><C-o>u
```

But in your case, as the undo modifies the buffer, this may not work under all circumstances.

Comment: Seems to work in the relevant cases. I'll simply do a follow up question, if I find a situation where there is still a problem. Thank you!